# JUnit5: Specify order of execution of multiple @Nested classes

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Does Junit5 give any guarantees regarding execution order of `@Nested` classes defined within the same parent? With a trivial example I made, I notice the tests are executed in reverse order of declaration, but this behavior is neither documented (or is it?) nor consistent with how `@Test` annotated methods are ordered by default.

It's also quite annoying, because obviously I'd rather have a non-reverse order, if not a way of configuring it akin to `@TestMethodOrder`.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class NestedOrderTest {
    @Nested
    class NestedTest1 {
        @Test
        void testSuccess1() {
            System.out.println(1);
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class NestedTest2 {
        @Test
        void testSuccess2() {
            System.out.println(2);
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class NestedTest3 {
        @Test
        void testSuccess3() {
            System.out.println(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
3
2
1
```

Comment: Caring about the order of test execution is a sign of dependencies between the tests, meaning the subsequent tests are (intentionally or not) using state changed by earlier tests. You should avoid this if at all possible.

Comment: @AndyTurner damn, I forgot the usual disclaimer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@Nested` class ordering feature has been added in [Junit 5.8](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order-classes). At this point, the platform gives all the guarantees users may need.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestClassOrder;

@TestClassOrder(ClassOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class OrderedNestedTestClassesDemo {

    @Nested
    @Order(1)
    class PrimaryTests {

        @Test
        void test1() {
        }
    }

    @Nested
    @Order(2)
    class SecondaryTests {

        @Test
        void test2() {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get import org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer; cannot be resolved.

Comment: @AndrewS you are obviously not includng the correct jar in your project: `'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1`

Comment: Jock, its not obvious but yes that is what was happening It seems that this feature was a recent introduction so if you do not have  5.8.1, or your IDE does not get this one for you, you have to figure out how to make it import the correct version. Especially when not working with the most recent Java versions.

Comment: don't forget to add `@TestClassOrder(ClassOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)` before class

Answer (score 3):

By default, unit testing libraries don't try to execute tests in the order that occurs in the source file.
JUnit 5 as JUnit 4 work in that way. Why ? Because if the order matters it means that  some tests are coupled between them and that is **undesirable for unit tests** (emphasis is mine) :

> 2.9. Test Execution Order
>
> **By default, test methods will be ordered using an algorithm that is
> deterministic but intentionally nonobvious**. This ensures that
> subsequent runs of a test suite execute test methods in the same
> order, thereby allowing for repeatable builds.

So it is expected that the `@Nested` feature introduced by JUnit 5 follows the same default approach.

**But for integration tests, the order of the test method may matter** since the state is not necessarily cleaned between the test methods executed.
So in JUnit 5 you have all the same the possibility to set the execution order by annotating the test class with [`@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)`](http://@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)) and by specifying the order with `@Order(numericOrderValue)` for the methods which the order matters.

But `@Order` is designed to decorate methods to test, not the test class itself as you would like :

```
@API(status = EXPERIMENTAL, since = "5.4")
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Order {...}
```

You can also note that that is an experimental feature.

So the single thing that you could order here are the test methods inside the same `@Nested` scope, for example :

```
@Nested
class NestedTest1 {

    @Order(3)
    @Test
    void success3() {
        System.out.println(3);
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Test
    void success2() {
        System.out.println(2);
    }

    @Order(1)
    @Test
    void success1() {
        System.out.println(1);
    }
}
```

Output :

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

By the way, specifying `@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)` looks like not needed (at least in the 5.4.0 version I tested).

Comment: The cited fragment of user guide about the test execution order is exactly why I am asking the question - I know there is sort of enforced reordering for Test methods, but my own observations do not prove the same applies to Nested elements. So do I assume that I got lucky with ordering of my executions, or is there something in the code that actually causes the ordering to be what it is - reversed declaration order.

Comment: All this answer states is whether or not it's a good idea to do so, and how to specify the order of methods, not nested classes. This does not answer the question.

Comment: This answer should be updated because JUnit provides @TestClassOrder since 5.8.